# Insert text to Word document

Tags: c#, ms-word

I would like to insert text to `Word` document, in a specified format, using `Interop.Word`:

Something like this :

```
wordDoc.InsertText("Text \n", "Arial");
```

or

```
wordDoc.InsertText("Text \n", "Bold");
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct method like this AFAIK. However, you can write a wrapper over Word Interop and do it. Internally inside your InsertText() method you will have to do the following.

1: Use the Text property of a Range object to insert text in a document.

```
object start = 0;
object end = 12; 
Word.Range rng = this.Range(ref start, ref end); 
rng.Text = "New Text"; 
rng.Select();
```

2: Format text using a document-level customization.

```
// Set the Range to the first paragraph. 
Word.Range rng = this.Paragraphs[1].Range;
// Change the formatting. 
rng.Font.Size = 14; 
rng.Font.Name = "Arial"; 
rng.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
rng.Select();
```

For further details please see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b9478cs.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b7k14a4.aspx) which I have used sometime back with good results.

Hope this helps.